# How to insert array values to different MySQL column

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array that contains multiple images directory that I defined as `$multipleDir`.

Also I have table named `product` that contains the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
  `mainimage` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `image1` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `image2` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `image3` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `image4` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `image5` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `image6` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `tags` varchar(1000) NOT NULL
)
```

`$multipleDir` contains 6 different images directory. My goal is to insert to each image column his own directory from the array.

Meaning:

```
Image1 column -> upload/image1.jpg 
Image2 column -> upload/image2.jpg 
Image3 column -> upload/image3.jpg
and so on..
```

My Insert code:

```
"INSERT INTO product (name, description, mainimage, image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, price, date, tags) VALUES ('". $productName ."', '". $productDescription ."', '". $newfilename ."', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', '". $price ."', '". $date ."', '". $tag ."')";
```

Each "test" represent image directory I want to apply.

I tried following the logic of `foreach` but it seems like the wrong approach because I can't control which value will be contained on each column.

How can I insert array values to different MySQL column?

My foreach approach:

```
foreach($multipleDir as $dir){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO product (name, description, mainimage, image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, price, date, tags) VALUES ('". $productName ."', '". $productDescription ."', '". $newfilename ."', '".$dir."', '".$dir."', '".$dir."', '".$dir."', '".$dir."', '".$dir."', '". $price ."', '". $date ."', '". $tag ."')";
}
```

Comment: wrong db structure. anyway, why do you think `foreach` approach is wrong? could you please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: @mitkosoft updated my approach.

Comment: Have a `productimage` table and associate images that way. Have `productid` and `image` in it. Also use prepared statements. This would be SQL injectable, always parameterize.

Comment: @user3783243 But I still don't know how to fill the productimage table with the array.

Comment: Roughly `prepare($query); foreach($array as $image) { execute(array($image, $productid)); }`

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove foreach and just use $multipleDir array by $multipleDir[0]...$multipleDir[5]

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO product (name, description, mainimage, image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, price, date, tags) VALUES ('". $productName ."', '". $productDescription ."', '". $newfilename ."', '".$multipleDir[0]."', '".$multipleDir[1]."', '".$multipleDir[2]."', '".$multipleDir[3]."', '".$multipleDir[4]."', '".$multipleDir[5]."', '". $price ."', '". $date ."', '". $tag ."')";
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the build-in `vsprintf()` function to create your query:

```
    $multipleDir = array(
        'upload/image1.jpg',
        'upload/image2.jpg',
        'upload/image3.jpg',
        'upload/image4.jpg',
        'upload/image5.jpg',
        'upload/image6.jpg'
    );
    $query = vsprintf(
        "INSERT INTO product (name, description, mainimage, image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, price, date, tags) VALUES ('". $productName ."', '". $productDescription ."', '". $newfilename ."', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '". $price ."', '". $date ."', '". $tag ."')",
        $multipleDir
    );
    echo $query;
```

Output:

```
INSERT INTO product (name, description, mainimage, image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, price, date, tags) VALUES ('', '', '', 'upload/image1.jpg', 'upload/image2.jpg', 'upload/image3.jpg', 'upload/image4.jpg', 'upload/image5.jpg', 'upload/image6.jpg', '', '', '')
```

Of course other values into produced SQL query are empty because I didn't init these variables.

Hope this helps.

P.S. `name` and `date` are reserved words in MySQL, so better use backquotes around all names into the query, like:

```
INSERT INTO `product` (`name`, `description`, `mainimage`, `image1`, `image2`, `image3`, `image4`, `image5`, `image6`, `price`, `date`, `tags`) VALUES ...
```

Comment: You should be using prepared statements. `vsprintf()` doesn't solve any issues.